# Determinate if the WallpaperService was ran by the app or Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Within the app, I call an intent to open the Android Native Live Wallpaper Preview Screen like this:

```
    val intent = Intent( WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER )
    intent.putExtra( WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
        ComponentName(
            this,
            RendererWallpaperService::class.java
        )
    )
    intent.putExtra( "testtt", 123 )
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    startActivity( intent )
```

And my **RendererWallpaperService** looks like this:

```
class RendererWallpaperService : WallpaperService()
{
    private var inputSensory : InputSensory?= null

    override fun onCreateEngine(): Engine
    {
        return GLESEngine()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    internal inner class GLESEngine : GLEngine()
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't access the '**testtt**' Extra from the intent from within the **RendererWallpaperService**. The **getIntent** method is available in Activity and since this is an **WallpaperService** class, there's no such method.

I was hoping to get the intent from the **onStartCommand**, but it never gets called ether (but the wallpaper works).

**All I want to do is to be able to distinguish if the Native Live Wallpaper Preview Screen was called from within the app or from Android->Live Wallpapers section.** I was hoping to simply pass the flag over the intent and that way I would know it was called from the app, otherwise if this flag is missing, then user opened the wallpaper through the android native UI.

How can I read the value from the intent or maybe there's a better way to determinate if the **RendererWallpaperService** was ran from the app itself or from native android wallpaper selection screen? Thank you!

Comment: "The problem is that I can't access the 'testtt' Extra from the intent from within the RendererWallpaperService" -- that extra is put on an `Intent` used with `startActivity()`. That `Intent` is unrelated to the `Intent` eventually used by the OS to start your service. "determinate if the RendererWallpaperService was ran from the app itself or from native android wallpaper selection screen?" -- it will be run by neither of those things directly, most likely. My expectation is that there are a few layers between those screens and the code that starts your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy hack:

```
private val changeWasOurs = false

class RendererWallpaperService : WallpaperService()
{
  companion object {
    fun setWasOurs() {
        changeWasOurs = true
    }
  }
}
```

The variable will be set to true when it was our change, and you can then skip it.  Remember to set the variable to false when done with each onStartCommand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping there will be more 'direct' approach, but this works out as expected, thanks again! :)

Comment: Its actually a fairly common pattern.  A lot of "subscribe to this event" in many OSes don't discriminate between events you cause and ones caused externally.  This general pattern of setting a local or global variable is common.

Answer (score 0):

`WallpaperService.Engine` has a method [`isPreview()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine#isPreview()) specifically to distinguish between the case where the user is previewing your live wallpaper in the `ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER` activity and the case where your live wallpaper is the active wallpaper for the device.

Comment: That's true, but it's irrelevant in this case as both cases are isPreview screen, but thanks!

Comment: It is not correct. Preview mode is mode with hidden button and icons. If you set a live wallpaper then it may be in normal mode (app mode) and you can set check box "preview".